# How to set vertical constraints in landscape orientation (Storyboard)

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard, xcode8, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to set a vertical space constraint of 8 between the "x" button and the bottom of the screen. However it isn't working as expected.

As you can see from the screen setting the constraint of -200 positions the "x" right there, and setting it to 8 would result it to be much higher up.

I've attached a screenshot below. Why is the logic different from that of a portrait orientation? And how do I correctly add the constraint?

[image: Vertical constraint]

Comment: Have you tried -8 or reversing the first and second items and using 8?

Comment: Yes I did. Reversing the first and second item have no difference, and using -8 just moves the x up even higher, considering with a -200 constraint its still not at the bottom of the screen

Comment: What other constraints have you set on the X?  What is the superview? Is it the root view or some other container?

Comment: Usually in IB you don't use negative constant values, at least not in my experience. Is creating the constraint programmatically an option? Sometimes I find that easier.

Comment: @Pierce Yeah I don't use negative constraint either, but 8 points from bottom doesn't seem to be working :/ I'd prefer creating it on IB though, as I need to support constraints for both portrait and landscape

Comment: @Paulw11 Oh my god. You're right, I did a really a silly mistake. Turns out the "x" is on another superview and it's not laid out correctly. Thanks for pointing that out. You can put that as an answer and I'd mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the constant (which you explain is your problem) the constraint looks correct. Make sure that you have constrained your item to the correct view. If there is another container view in your scene it may be constrained to that by mistake.